# Cannot install NetBeans on Ubuntiu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, netbeans-7

I am a new Ubuntu user, in fact, new to Unix/Linux. I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I need to install NetBeans 7.2 on Ubuntu. I have already installed JDK using commands form [this](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) link. The JDK is installed in **/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0**.

Now when I use the command **sudo sh ~/Downloads/netbeans-7.2-ml-linux.sh**, it searches for JVM but cannot find it. I get a message saying **JDK 6 is required for installing the NetBeans.......**.

I set the environment variable for **JAVA_HOME** using the command `sudo gedit /etc/environment` and adding this line in the file that was opened in **gedit** - `JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0"`. Then I restarted the laptop. I still cannot install NetBeans since the setup cannot find JDK.

Using `echo $PATH` does echo the value for **PATH** environment variable, but using `echo $JAVA_HOME` echoes a blank line.

What should I do to install NetBeans?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this procedure:

http://connectwww.com/how-to-install-netbeans-ide-on-ubuntu-12-04/2286/

Comment: For your information, as I mentioned in my original post, I have installed the JDK already. The NetBeans just doesn't recognize JDK.